Deprecated API on GKE
How can I check deprecated API on GKE while upgrading cluster suppose 1.27 to 1.28. What to do to against the deprecated API? Any guidance will be appreciated. I have gone through gcp docs but didn't help in my case.

use 'kubectl' command
it will show you all resources that are deprecated in your current cluster version

kubectl api-resources --verbs=list --api-group=extensions,v1beta1

visit the Kubernetes official documentation for the version 1.28, look for the section on deprecated APIs and features and find the alternatives mentioned.
once you find  the deprecated APIs, update your configurations to use the recommended alternatives

@prototoak as per gcp document it is mentioned that if any deprecated feature or API is there we can check from Notification section of any cluster and we can check that insight or recommendation. Is it correct to identify ?Deprecated/removed  API. I have used cli tool Pluto to identify the same.

@Schatt  using GCP's notification section to identify deprecated features or APIs is indeed a valid approach. GCP often sends notifications to alert users about deprecated features, APIs, or other changes that may affect their resources. These notifications typically provide insights or recommendations on how to address the deprecations. Also, pluto is made to check GKE clusters and give information about old APIs, future changes, or other problems that could affect how your cluster works or performs. So you can use both methods in combination as well.
